# how to get max in linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i have some table in dataBase. `INV`,`LIB`,`TRAN_TT1` datatype all field in 3 table are string . i write this code

```
 var m = new MaterialModelContainer();
            var list = (from inv in m.INVs
                        where inv.NEW_QTY == "000000"
                        join lib in m.LIBs on inv.MESC equals lib.MESC
                        join tt1 in m.TRAN_TT1 on inv.MESC equals tt1.MESC4
                        where tt1.TYPE2 == "60" && tt1.QTY == "000000" 
                       select new
                                   {
                                       inv.MESC,
                                       lib.LINE_NO,
                                       lib.UNIT_LINE,
                                       Description = lib.DES + " " + lib.PART_NO,

                                   }).ToList();
```

table `TRAN_TT1` has a ACTD field, i want get max value 
i write this code

```
 var m = new MaterialModelContainer();
            var list = (from inv in m.INVs
                        where inv.NEW_QTY == "000000"
                        join lib in m.LIBs on inv.MESC equals lib.MESC
                        join tt1 in m.TRAN_TT1 on inv.MESC equals tt1.MESC4
                        where tt1.TYPE2 == "60" && tt1.QTY == "000000" 
                       select new
                                   {
                                       inv.MESC,
                                       lib.LINE_NO,
                                       lib.UNIT_LINE,
                                       Description = lib.DES + " " + lib.PART_NO,
                                     ACTD=  tt1.ACTD.Max()
                                   }).ToList();
```

but no work,

please help me to get max ACTD field . thanks all

Comment: how is it not working? are you getting an error?

Comment: What is the datatype of `ACTD`?

Comment: @  Nikhil Agrawal : dateType is string

Comment: @ jb : yes i get this error : Unable to process the type 'System.Char', because it has no known mapping to the value layer

Comment: @mohsen: Compile time or runtime error and in which line are you getting this.?

Comment: @ Nikhil Agrawal : in run time

Comment: What kind of data you storing in that field? Seems you using incorrect fields types. For example quantity you storing as string, why? I think max will return longest string. Is that what you looking for?

Comment: @ Reniuz : in yhis filed stroe example this data 890107

Comment: Why you store numbers as string?

Comment: @ Reniuz : The database does not belong to me , And I can only run queries on it, please help me. thanks

Comment: If you want to get biggest number in  that field, first you need to parse it as int and then get max.

Comment: no store biggest number in this filed, max 6 digit save in this filed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max is a aggregate function, and the aggregate functions in Linq has the same restrictions like in SQL - if you use aggregate function for one of the column - all other using columns should be also used in aggregate functions or you should use GroupBy by them. 
So your sample should be something like:

```
var m = new MaterialModelContainer();
            var list = (from x in 

                       (from inv in m.INVs
                        where inv.NEW_QTY == "000000"
                        join lib in m.LIBs on inv.MESC equals lib.MESC
                        join tt1 in m.TRAN_TT1 on inv.MESC equals tt1.MESC4
                        where tt1.TYPE2 == "60" && tt1.QTY == "000000" 
                        select new {inv.MESC, lib.LINE_NO, lib.UNIT_LINE, Description = lib.DES + " " + lib.PART_NO, tt1.ACTD})

                        group by new {x.MESC, x.LINE_NO, x.UNIT_LINE, x.Description} into g
                        select new {g.Key.MESC, g.Key.LINE_NO, g.Key.UNIT_LINE, g.Key.Description, ACTDMax = g.Max(tt2 => tt2.ACTD) } );
```

Comment: this query is work thanks for help me. but in group line after group should add X . thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
ACTD = tt1.ACTD.Max(x => x);
```

Comment: @ Nikhil Agrawal : when i write this code i get this error : DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
Parameter name: input

Comment: @ Nikhil Agrawal: Why do you think this code not run. please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

not sure, but from the error 
try

```
ACTD= ((int?) tt1.ACTD).Max()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write this code for get max ACTD value

```
  var m = new MaterialModelContainer();
            var list = (from x in

                            (from inv in m.INVs
                             where inv.NEW_QTY == "000000"
                             join lib in m.LIBs on inv.MESC equals lib.MESC
                             join tt1 in m.TRAN_TT1 on inv.MESC equals tt1.MESC4
                             where tt1.TYPE2 == "60" && tt1.QTY == "000000"
                             select
                                 new
                                     {
                                         inv.MESC,
                                         lib.LINE_NO,
                                         lib.UNIT_LINE,
                                         Description = lib.DES + " " + lib.PART_NO,
                                         tt1.ACTD
                                     })

                        group x by new {x.MESC, x.LINE_NO, x.UNIT_LINE, x.Description}
                        into g
                        select
                            new
                                {
                                    g.Key.MESC,
                                    g.Key.LINE_NO,
                                    g.Key.UNIT_LINE,
                                    g.Key.Description,
                                    ACTDMax = g.Max(tt2 => tt2.ACTD)
                                }
                                ).OrderBy(c=>c.MESC).ToList();
```